# Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory when starting iptables service

Tags: centos, iptables

I have a CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

when I try to start service iptables

```
# service iptables start 
Opening /proc/modules: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install iptables service

```
yum erase iptables
yum install iptables
```

Same message; then I have an issue while running php applications

Do you have an idea to create this file?
I don't have a `/proc/modules.swp` file

the output of `cat /proc/modules`

```
cat /proc/modules
cat: /proc/modules: no such file or directory
```

in other hand

```
# du -h --max-depth=1 /
4,0K    /run
530M    /root
16K     /lost+found
23M     /sbin
4,1M    /lib
18M     /lib64
82M     /opt
du: impossible d'accéder à « /proc/2625/task/2625/fd/3 »: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
du: impossible d'accéder à « /proc/2625/task/2625/fdinfo/3 »: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
du: impossible d'accéder à « /proc/2625/fd/4 »: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
du: impossible d'accéder à « /proc/2625/fdinfo/4 »: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
0       /proc
196K    /dev
4,0K    /srv
4,0K    /cgroup
43M     /etc
4,0K    /selinux
7,6G    /home
7,2M    /bin
112K    /tmp
2,5G    /usr
du: impossible d'accéder à « /sys/kernel/slab/L2TP/IPv6 »: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
du: impossible d'accéder à « /sys/kernel/slab/L2TP/IP »: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
0       /sys
4,0K    /media
14M     /boot
4,0K    /mnt
14G     /var
25G     /
```

**df output**

```
# df
Filesystem      1K-blocks     Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /
devtmpfs         16305868      196   16305672   1% /dev
/dev/md2           248719    15309     220358   7% /boot
/dev/md4       1901278324  7955704 1796720256   1% /home
/dev/sda1          522228     1084     521144   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs            16341168        0   16341168   0% /dev/shm
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/etc/named
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/var/named
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/etc/services
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/etc/protocols
/dev/root        20026172 17923180    1079048  95% /var/named/chroot/lib64/libnss_files.so.2
```

## ls -l /proc/modules

no such file or directory

If I try to recover the file from a swap file, even if I am connected as root, I am not allowed to save the file; as if the file was locked by other service

## vi -r /proc/modules

llc 5546 2 bridge,stp, Live 0x0000000000000000
ipt_REJECT 2351 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
iptable_filter 2793 1 - Live 0x0000000000000000
ip_tables 17831 1 iptable_filter, Live 0x0000000000000000
autofs4 26513 3 - Live 0x0000000000000000
vsock 46630 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
ipv6 318183 208 - Live 0x0000000000000000
ppdev 8537 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
vmware_balloon 7199 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
parport_pc 22690 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
parport 36209 2 ppdev,parport_pc, Live 0x0000000000000000
microcode 112685 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
e1000 170678 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
sg 29350 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
vmci 75631 1 vsock, Live 0x0000000000000000
i2c_piix4 12608 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
i2c_core 31084 1 i2c_piix4, Live 0x0000000000000000
shpchp 32778 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
ext4 374917 3 - Live 0x0000000000000000
jbd2 93427 1 ext4, Live 0x0000000000000000
mbcache 8193 1 ext4, Live 0x0000000000000000
sd_mod 39069 5 - Live 0x0000000000000000
crc_t10dif 1541 1 sd_mod, Live 0x0000000000000000
sr_mod 15177 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
cdrom 39085 1 sr_mod, Live 0x0000000000000000
mptsas 52672 3 - Live 0x0000000000000000
mptscsih 36700 1 mptsas, Live 0x0000000000000000
mptbase 93647 2 mptsas,mptscsih, Live 0x0000000000000000
scsi_transport_sas 35652 1 mptsas, Live 0x0000000000000000
pata_acpi 3701 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
ata_generic 3837 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
ata_piix 24601 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
dm_mirror 14384 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
dm_region_hash 12085 1 dm_mirror, Live 0x0000000000000000
dm_log 9930 2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash, Live 0x0000000000000000
dm_mod 84337 13 dm_mirror,dm_log, Live 0x0000000000000000
"/proc/modules"
"/proc/modules" E212: Can't open file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue

/proc is already mounted but I can't write in it

## mount -t proc proc /proc

mount: proc already mounted

## ls -l | grep proc

drwxr-xr-x 252 root root     0 27 déc.  15:03 proc

## cp /modules.ppz /home/

==> no problem

## cp /modules.ppz /proc/

cp: impossible to create the standard file « /proc/modules.ppz »: no file or directory

Comment: Why `/proc/modules.swp`? It should read `/proc/modules`.

Comment: What output do you get from  `cat /proc/modules`?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /proc/modules` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick If `cat` can't find the file, why should `ls`?

Comment: @Murphy It was just a question to see if some symlink or overlayfs weirdness was going on. I guess I should have first asked if this is a VM or container or being hosted somewhere. It's possible the kernel was built without module support, but that's rare. Some hosting providers give customers kernels like that.